# How to pass parent key to child in nested *ngFor angular

Tags: angular, foreach, nested-loops, ngfor

I need to pass the key of parent loop to another array. But it is not working . Below is my code

```
<div  *ngFor="let con_settings of contact_settings | keyvalue">
 <h5 class="mt-0 task-header header-title">{{contact_settings_title.key}}</h5>
</div>
```

contact_settings_title is another array

```
contact_settings=[
{'first':['1','2']}
{'second':['3','4']}
]

contact_settings_title=[
    {'first':FirstTitle},
    {'second':SecondTitle}
]
```

Comment: Do you mean `contact_settings_title[key]`? Exactly what and how do you need to pass the key to the other array?

Comment: {{ contact_settings_title[con_settings.key] }} isn't working?

Comment: @MehranBeiglou no it is not working

Comment: @MikeS. I have posted the array , pls chk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div  *ngFor="let con_settings of contact_settings | keyvalue">
 <h5 class="mt-0 task-header header-title">{{ contact_settings_title[key] }}</h5>
</div>
```